# Is it possible to change behavior of org-store-link to insert :CUSTOM_ID: property instead of :ID:?

Tags: org-mode

I use `org-store-link` pretty often for setting unique IDs to org-mode nodes. I have the following option set in my init file to make this possible:

```el
(setq org-id-link-to-org-use-id 'create-if-interactive-and-no-custom-id)
```

But for my use case, I would like them to be `CUSTOM_ID` properties, rather than `ID` properties, so I end up changing it each time, which is a bit annoying. Is it possible to have `org-store-link` insert `CUSTOM_ID` properties, instead of `ID` properties, when the option is set as above?

Just to be clear, this is only for Org mode buffers.

---

Update. :CUSTOM_ID: is used for basic navigation between(and within) org files:

```
[[#02363be6-0855-4e57-aa94-5663c6fa8451][internal link to Foo]]
[[file:README.org::#02363be6-0855-4e57-aa94-5663c6fa8451][link to Foo from other file]]

* Foo
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID:       02363be6-0855-4e57-aa94-5663c6fa8451
:END:
```

Comment: How do you use `org-store-link` to set unique IDs? These seem completely unrelated operations. I don't understand what you are doing or what exactly you are asking. An example might help.

Comment: @NickD
How do I use org-store-link - I navigate to a node in org file(like "Foo" in the example below) that, I run `org-store-link` and it inserts an :ID: property which I rename to CUSTOM_ID

Comment: "...it inserts an :ID: property" - not here, it doesn't. You must have extra machinery in play to do that. Does it happen when you start with `emacs -q`?

Comment: @NickD Extra machinery might be `(setq org-id-link-to-org-use-id 'create-if-interactive-and-no-custom-id)` in my config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't answer the original question fully but as a workaround I used the following:

Create an interactive function and bind it to your preferred shortcut:

```lisp
(org-set-property "CUSTOM_ID" (uuidgen-1))
```